# configurar mail laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Actualmente deseo configurar mi aplicación en **Laravel** con datos dinámicos de base de datos para el envió de correo. Es decir, `host, port, driver, user, password` quiero tomarlos de base de datos. ¿Como puedo realizar la configuración?

En el `config/mail.php` se encuentran los valores que se pasan al `.env`. ¿Hay forma de pasarle una variable con los datos de todos los campos?

```
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
```

lo modifique a esto y continua sin funcionar como mencionas

```
`$conf = ConfMail::find(1);

    config([
        'mail.driver' => $conf->driver,
        'mail.host' => $conf->host,
        'mail.port' => $conf-port,
        'mail.from' => [
            'mail.address' => $conf->email,
            'mail.name' => $conf->name],
        'mail.encryption' => $conf->encryption,
        'mail.username' => $conf->user,
        'mail.password' => $conf->password
    ]);
```

no se si al config le falte algo.

Comment: creo, si no me equivoco, que seria `'mail.from.address' => $conf->mail` y `'mail.from.name' => $conf->name`, si esto no te funciona, intenta colocar directamente las credenciales en el fichero .env en tu directorio raiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes modificar los valores de configuración durante la ejecución de la aplicación

```
config([
       'mail.driver' => $driver,
       'mail.host' => $host,
       'mail.port' => $port
       ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: Esa configuración la puedo anexar en mi controlador? o en que parte debería ir?

Comment: Si, dentro de la función que necesites, tal y como esta.

Comment: ok. fíjate estoy colocando lo de la siguiente manera.


`$conf = ConfMail::find(1);

        config([
            'mail.driver' => $conf->driver,
            'mail.host' => $conf->host,
            'mail.port' => $conf-port,
            'mail.from' => [
                'mail.address' => $conf->email,
                'mail.name' => $conf->name],
            'mail.encryption' => $conf->encryption,
            'mail.username' => $conf->user,
            'mail.password' => $conf->password
        ]);`

y no envía el correo creo que no esta llegando la configuración.

Comment: Intenta obtener la configuración con el siguiente `comando,config('app.timezone');` después de setearla claro, y te debe de dar la misma configuración que estas seteando con `$conf`

Comment: si me retorno UTC

Comment: `config('mail');`

Comment: perfecto amigo funciono. el error de que no me retornara nada era que tenia un error en el codigo. donde estaba `$conf-port,` le faltaba  `$conf->port,` gracias por la respuesta